# Odd/curious behaviour in a recursive function

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am trying to program a function checking whether or not a string is the result of set of actions on previous string. Specifically, a string 'b' is a transformation of string 'a' if it follows the same order of characters, has only the same characters, yet may have them multiplied. For example:
`"aabba"` is a transformation  of `"aba"` however not of `"abaa"`, as that has double `'a'` at the end.

The code is as follows:

```
public static boolean isTrans(String s, String t)
{
    if(s.equals(t)){return true;} //obviously the latter is transformation
    else if(s.length()==0||t.length()==0){return false;} //either is empty, can't be transformation
    else if(s.charAt(0)!=t.charAt(0)){return false;} //obviously not transformation
    else {return (s.length()==(isTrans(s,0,t,1)));} //recursive method below, note s.charAt(0)==t.charAt(0).
}
private static int isTrans(String s, int i, String t, int j)
{
    if(i < s.length() && j < t.length()) //only as long as the indexes are within right bound
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(j)) //character at 'transformed' string is the character at original string
        {
            if((j+1)<t.length()) //only as long as there are more characters
            {
                j++;
                isTrans(s,i,t,j); //check next character at transformed string
            }
        }
        else if((i+1)<s.length()) //ensures there is a next character at string s
        {
            if(s.charAt(i+1) == t.charAt(j)) //character is the next chracter at original string
            {
                i++;
                if((j+1)<t.length()) //only as long as there are more characters
                {
                    j++;
                    isTrans(s,i,t,j); //checks next characters at strings
                }
            }
            else{i=-1;} //not transformation
        }
        else{i=-1;} //not transformation
    }    
    return (i+1);
}
```

The program doesn't work as intended. **Now here is the curious thing:** running it through the debugger, it does everything as intended, however, when it reaches the "`return (i+1)`" command, instead of actually returning it, it starts to execute the recursive calls for some reason, meanwhile decreasing the value of `i`, until it reaches 0, and only then returning it, causing false negatives. More specifically, it goes up the stack and 'executes' the recursive calls of `isTrans(s,i,t,j)`.

I would like to know *why* it does that, even more than a way to solve such a problem. It doesn't even enters through the iff's, but immediately enters the recursive calls, reducing the value of `i` all the way to 0 and only then returning it.

Appreciate any comments!

**Edit:** to clarify what exactly it does, according to the debugger. If I try to see if `"aabba"` is a transformation of `"aba"` (it is under the definitions above), the program reaches the desired value for `i` - `2`. However, it then reaches the command `return (i+1)`, and suddenly returns to line 17 in the given code, then the next recursive call in the code, and back to it - all the meanwhile reducing the value of `i` back to `0`. Only then it executes the command outside of the function.

**Edit 2:** After a bit of tweaking and playing with the code, it seems that **without connection to the return statement**, at the end the function 'jumps' backwards, skipping through the 'if's, to the recursive calls - does not execute them, yet reduces `i` to `0` and only then continues. Does it have something to do with me calling isTrans(s,**0**,t,1)?

Comment: Are you sure it goes *down* the stack instead of *up*? In other words, are you sure that the function you were in was not a recursive invocation and the return statement brought you back?

Comment: I don't know what string transformation is. Can you please give some explamples of some strings that are/aren't transformations of each other (and why)? Also you compare strings using `==`, you udefinetly want to change that to `.equals()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: You're not using the return value of `isTrans()` when calling it recursively, could that be causing problems? The first call will always return something in [-1, 1].

Comment: String equality isn't tested with `s == t`.

Comment: Recursion is always odd and curious.  You must be doing it right!

Comment: And note that nothing done inside your method escapes from the method -- none of the parms are modified and the return value is unused.  It's not likely to produce any useful results that way.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, will update the question to clarify.

Comment: @HotLicks care to clarify what you mean that nothing done inside escapes it? The return value is used in the `isTrans(s,t)`.

@univerio it did bring me back, but to the specific recursive calls inside the function, skipping all the if's along the way. I can't see why it would do that.

Comment: Your two calls from within isTrans(s,i,t,j) have no effect -- might as well not do the calls.

Comment: They are needed in order for the function to check all the leters and get i to the right value. Otherwise it would return a too low i value. At least it does that well at the debugger, am I missing something?

Comment: If you commented out those calls it would function exactly the same, save for any exceptions they might throw.  If you look, *they are not changing anything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exit condition is `return i+1`. This will never work, even if your logic did, because the result you are returning is always one more than the length of the String.

Here is what likely happens in your code:

1. First if condition is satisfied
2. j is incremeanted.
3. Recursive call.
4. No more if conditions are satisfied, because i and j no longer point to the same letter.
5. It returns i+1

To do this recursively you would probably do something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = "aba";
        String t = "abz";
        System.out.println(isTrans(0, 0, s, t));
    }

    public static boolean isTrans(int si, int ti,String s ,String t)
    {
        // we have run out of source characters, or the source character has passed the transformation character. This is not a transformation.
        if (si > ti || si == s.length())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // we are at the end of the transformation string. This might be a transformation.
        if(ti == t.length())
        {
            return si == s.length()-1; // If we're at the end of our source string, otherwise it isn't.
        }

        // if the current positions contain identical characters...
        if (checkChar(si, ti, s, t))
        {
            // advance the transformation index.
            ti++; 
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise, advance the source index.
            si++;
        }

        // recursion.
        return isTrans(si, ti, s, t);
    }

    private static boolean checkChar(int si, int ti, String s, String t)
    {
        return  (s.charAt(si) == t.charAt(ti));
    }

}
```

Hope you found it helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear what transformation is for me, updated the original question with it. "aba" is a transformation of "aba" under my defintion, and so is "aaba", "aabbbbbba" and so on. The exit condition is `return i+1`, not minus 1.

Comment: @Studentmath I have changed my answer to better reflect your updated question. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think I understand now what I did wrong, and I think I understand how to implement your idea to solve my problem. Thank you very much, it did clarify!